# Proper way to do request logging in Unload event in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

The [Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) suggests "finishing up logging or other request-specific tasks" in the Unload event on the page. This perplexes me because we no longer have the Request object at that point, and consequently we can't access things like Request.Url and Request["__EVENTTARGET"]. The MS article on the Unload event itself doesn't say anything about logging; it's just the page lifecycle overview, that I can find, that suggests this.

My question is: I'm wondering what the "proper" solution might be.

Logging in Render "almost" seems like an OK solution, but some commercial user controls I'm using call Page.Render multiple times (Unload is still only called once). I can get around this issue by using Render to add some entries into HttpContext.Current.Items for the Request details I need, and then grabbing those in the Unload event. However, this sort of feels "dirty". There must be a reason that Unload is recommended for logging.